Logarithmic trig equation. Why is my solution wrong?
This is the problem: $\log^2_{4}{\cos2x} = \log_{\frac{1}{16}}{\cos2x}$.
My solution:
$$\log^2_{4}{\cos2x} = -\frac{1}{2}\log_{4}{\cos2x}$$
$$\log_{4}{\cos2x}(\log_{4}{\cos2x} + \frac{1}{2}) = 0$$
$$\cos2x=1, \cos2x=4^{-0.5}, \cos2x > 0$$
$$\sin{x} = 0, \cos2x=\frac{1}{2}, \cos2x > 0.$$
$\cos2x > 0$ is satisfied because $\frac12>0$.
$$\ \ x_1 = \pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}, \cos{2x}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos{2x} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$2\cos^2{x} - 1 = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos^2{x} = \frac{3}{4}$$
$$\cos{x}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$x_2 = \pm\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n, n\in\mathbb{Z}, \ \ x_3 = \pm\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi m, m\in\mathbb{Z}$$
The correct answer only includes $x_1$ and $x_2$, while I also get $x_3$. Why am I wrong?

Check the correct answer, it probably has $x_2 = \pm\frac{\pi}{6}+\pi n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ which is the same as your $x_2$ and $x_3$

When taking $\cos 2x = \frac12$ directly, we get $x=\pm\frac\pi/6+k\pi$, which is equivalent to your $x_2$ and $x_3$. Is it how it is written in the answer keys?

You need $\cos(2x)>0$ for the left and right side to even be defined. Then first let $y=\cos(2x)$ and solve for $y.$ Then solve $y=\cos(2x)$ for $x$ for each possible $y.$ Solving altogether makes it much harder to read,

This answer is fine, except $x_2,x_3$ can be combined to $\pm\frac\pi6+k\pi.$
Of course, $\log(\cos(2x))$ is undefined if $\cos(2x)\leq0,$ so this problem demands $\cos(2x)>0.$
It is usually easier to solve this sort of problem in parts. Let $\theta=2x, y=\cos\theta=\cos(2x),$ then first solve for $y,$ then $\theta,$ then $x.$ Even if, as you've shown, you can solve it this way, you will appreciate learning this technique for future problems.
Since $\log_{a}b=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a},$ then $$\log_{1/16} y=\frac{\ln y}{\ln(1/16)}=\frac{\ln(y)}{-2\ln(4)}=-\frac12\log_4y.$$
So you are correct, the equation becomes $$\log_4^2y=-\frac12\log_4y,$$ Which mean either $\log_4y=0$ or $\log_4(y)=-\frac12,$ which gives $y=4^0=1$ or $y=4^{-1/2}=\frac12.$
So you need $\cos(\theta)=1$ or $\cos(\theta)=\frac12.$
$\cos(\theta)=1$ iff $\theta=2k\pi$ for some integer $k,$ or $x=\frac{\theta}2=k\pi.$
$\cos(\theta)=\frac12$ iff $\theta=\pm\frac\pi3+2k\pi$ or $x=\pm\frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi.$
The reason you missed that $x_2,x_3$ can be combined is that you solve for $\cos(x)$ in terms of $\cos(2x)$ and then solved for $x.$ It doesn't give a wrong answer, but it is more complicated.
